# bullet points from <ul>

Tags: html, css, web, html-lists

This is a question that has been answered a milion times but non of the fixes work for me, therefore im here.

```
css: ul li {display:inline-block; }

<ul class="no-bullet">
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><div class="yticon"><img id="social_me" src="https://arcofilms.com/onovo/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/youtube-3-512.png" alt="Youtube" width="35" height="35" /></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><div class="faceicon"><img id="social_me" src="https://arcofilms.com/onovo/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/facebook-symbol_318-37686.jpg" alt="Facebook In" width="35" height="35" /></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="social_me" src="https://arcofilms.com/onovo/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/60818.png" alt="Google Plus" width="35" height="35" /></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https:https://vimeo.com" target="_blank"><img id="social_me" src="https://arcofilms.com/onovo/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/vimeo-xxl.png" alt="Vimeo" width="35" height="35" /></a>
</li></ul>
```

[social media icon bullets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hx4a.png)
https://arcofilms.com/onovo the link

if somneone could be of help would be awesome
if you know a better way of doing this im open to suggestions too! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just want the bullets gone?

In that case, use this CSS:

```
ul.no-bullet {padding-left:0;}
ul.no-bullet > li {list-style:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the list items to display no bullet points:

```
ul li {
  display:inline-block; 
  list-style: none;
 }
```

..or as you already have a helper class:

```
.no-bullet li {list-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in you css

```
ul li  {list-style-type: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this has been answered a million times.
You can use

> list-style-type: none

just make a little change in your css:

```
ul { list-style-type: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below css code for remove border. because bullets is display by using border

```
#footer-widgets .footer-widget li::before{border:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
    .no-bullet {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .no-bullet li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Works for me.